# Mixing std::time in with random ints

Tags: c++, cryptography, xor

We use xor to combine random integers for seeding a random number generator. We've been asked to 'add more sources' to the mix. However, all of the good random sources are already in the mix, so it was suggested that we add std::time( now ). It's easy to add, but my concern is, could adding that weaken the pool? It's not random nor uniformly distributed, etc. My gut says it can't hurt, but I'm not positive. Here's how the code looks:

```
int r1 = random1;
int r2 = random2;
int r3 = random3;

int r4 = (r1 ^ r2) ^ r3;
```

Should time be added, it might look like this:

```
int r4 = ((r1 ^ r2) ^ r3) ^ std::time( now );
```

Will adding time to the mix weaken it?

Comment: `It's not random nor uniformly distributed` That can happen if you mix different uniform sources, and that´s why mixing is a bad idea (because your cryptographically secure randum number suddenly gets a lot more predictable). Use *one* good algo. (And "xor time" won´t make anything better)

Comment: If you really want to use custom seeding for a CSPRNG (usually it's better to leave that to the OS), simply concatenate all the seed material and leave the rest to the entropy extractor of the CSPRNG. Don't try to be cute with those xors.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe this would hurt anything. If `r1`, `r2`, and `r3` are still unknown/completely random, `r4` will also remain completely random.

Let's suppose:

- `r1 = 390866135;`
- `r2 = 879333620;`
- `r3 = 986588813;` and
- `currentTime = 1421364812;`

Now if we XOR these variables:

- `r1 ^ r2 = 589673507`
- `589673507 ^ r3 = 434868910`
- `434868910 ^ currentTime = 1297341666`

So the final random number ends up being `1297341666`. Even if you are given the current `std::time(now)`, the final random number will be unpredictable because you do not know `r1`, `r2`, or `r3`.

For more information (and probably a better explanation), check out [this question from Cryptography Stack Exchange.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17658/mixing-entropy-sources-by-xor)

To quote the author of that answer:

> If one source remains uncompromised plus statistically random on all bits, and both sources remain independent, then a xor of both sources together can also be considered uncompromised plus statistically random for all bits.

Answer (score 0):

Most operating systems come with a built in source of randomness, which reads from a lot of very low-level sources -- the kind of thing it is tedious to access directly from a program.  Unix: dev/random or Windows: CryptGenRandom are obvious examples.

Depending on how fast and how secure you want your RNG, then passing the result through a cryptographic hash will held smooth out any non-randomness in your inputs.